# Find all words starts with @@ and ends with @@ in long string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I have a quite big string. In that big string, I want to get all UNIQUE words starts with @@ and ends with @@. Between @@ could be text, number or alphanumeric or anything.

Once I get all the UNIQUE words starting @@ and ends with @@, I want to replace each word with   a value which matches a key in a different array.

Looking for the solution in C#.

Comment: I don't understand why so many insist on using regex when there's both [`string.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx), [`string.StartsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith.aspx) and [`string.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) which does it equally well (and for me in a more readable way).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
@@\b\S+?\b@@
```

Sample Code:

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>();
MatchCollection mcol = Regex.Matches(sampleString,@"@@\b\S+?\b@@");

foreach(Match m in mcol)
{
    lst.Add(m.Tostring());
}
```

Here `lst` contains matched value(s), compare each value and replace it as per you criteria.

#### [Sample live demo](http://rubular.com/r/N5LSG3EASq)

Comment: Your pattern isn't suitable. The `\b` will cause the pattern to match at an undesired offset. The pattern should be *@@\b(?<word>.+?)\b@@*

Comment: @ByteBlast, it worked with your suggestion. except the regular expression. your code works good.

Comment: @ByteBlast: `@@\b(.+?)\b@@` won't necessarily work either.  It assumes the first and last character of the "word" will always be a word character (i.e., a character that matches `\w+`).  From what the OP has said so far, it doesn't sound like a safe assumption.  And if you know the first and last will always be word characters, `\b` is redundant.

Comment: @NeverH, you should be using a verbatim string, i.e., `@"..."`.  As it is, you're trying to match a substring that starts and ends with backspaces.

Comment: @AlanMoore, agreed. Thank you for highlighting.

Comment: In the string "@@bb@@ @@cc@@ @@sahasjah@@ @@bb@@ @@hello @@how @invensys@@". output should be @@bb@@ @@cc@@ @@sahasjah@@ @@bb@@. currently it shows @@hello also which is wrong as there is a space after hello. please advice

Comment: @NeverHopeless, Thanks for your quick turnaround. that works.

Answer (score 1):

Example using Regex and Linq

```
string text = "@@bb@@@@cc@@@@sahasjah@@@@bb@@";
var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"@@[^@]*@@");
var uniques = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(match => match.Value).ToList().Distinct();
```

Comment: Why are you using the `Singleline` option?  There are no dots (`.`) in your regex.

Comment: In the string "@@bb@@ @@cc@@ @@sahasjah@@ @@bb@@ @@hello @@how @invensys@@". output should be @@bb@@ @@cc@@ @@sahasjah@@ @@bb@@. currently it shows @@hello also which is wrong as there is a space after hello. please advice.

Answer (score 1):

Try following code (use [Regex.Replace Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx)):

```
string s = @"@@Welcome@@ to @@reg-ex@@ @@world@@.";
Dictionary<string, string> sub = new Dictionary<string,string>{
    { "@@reg-ex@@", "regular expression" },
    { "@@world@@", "hell" },
};
Regex re = new Regex(@"@@.*?@@");
Console.WriteLine(re.Replace(s, x => {
    string new_x;
    return sub.TryGetValue(x.ToString(), out new_x) ? new_x : x.ToString();
}));
```

prints:

```
@@Welcome@@ to regular expression hell.
```

Comment: In the string "@@bb@@ @@cc@@ @@sahasjah@@ @@bb@@ @@hello @@how @invensys@@". output should be @@bb@@ @@cc@@ @@sahasjah@@ @@bb@@. currently it shows @@hello also which is wrong as there is a space after hello. please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe do the following

```
Regex regex = new Regex("@@(.*)@@");
```

Or, if you dont want Regex use the following (easier to understand i think)

```
var splittedString = yourString.Split(new string[] { "xx" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: In the string "@@bb@@ @@cc@@ @@sahasjah@@ @@bb@@ @@hello @@how @invensys@@". output should be @@bb@@ @@cc@@ @@sahasjah@@ @@bb@@. currently it shows @@hello also which is wrong as there is a space after hello. please advice

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular expression @@.+?@@ to replace your special string tokens.

Use [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx) to find and replace matching tokens.

Comment: In the string "@@bb@@ @@cc@@ @@sahasjah@@ @@bb@@ @@hello @@how @invensys@@". output should be @@bb@@ @@cc@@ @@sahasjah@@ @@bb@@. currently it shows @@hello also which is wrong as there is a space after hello. please advice

Answer (score 0):

Try this one mate.....

```
string yourString = ""; // Load your string
string[] splits = Regex.Split(yourString, "[ \n\t]"); //Split the long string by spaces, \t and \n
foreach (string str in splits)
{
    if(Regex.IsMatch(str, "^^@@.*?@@$$")) // Find words starting and ending with @@
    {
        // You may replace either splits values or build a new string according your specification
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use regexp for that. This is faster :

```
//Pseudo code
string[] parts = yourLongString.split("@@");
for(i=0;i<parts.length;i++){
    if(parts[i].indexOf(' ')<0){
        // there is no space, it is a keyword
        parts[i]=yourDictionary[parts[i]];
    }
}
yourFinalText=parts.join(' ');
```

Comment: In the longstring the keyword which start with @@samplestring@@ may repeate more than once. in this case if I can find and replace as you mentioned is good. but how do i get all the UNIQUE keys in the longstring into an array or List? In the long string there may be words which starts with @@ but does not end with @@. I want to ignore them in my keyword list. my keyword list should only contain words which starts with @@ and ends with @@.

Comment: So just change the loop. Check for space. If there's no space then it is a keyword and you must replace it. I update the code.